# Python extract single quotes from double quotes

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a list of text like this:

```
"DATA - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'"
"DATA - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'"
'DATA - SOM THIN Escalation'
'DATA - SOM THIN HEARTBEAT Escalation'
"DATA - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'"
"DATA - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'"
"DATA - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'"
```

I would like to extract the `''` part of the string from `""`.
What is the best way to do this? What is the difference between `'` and `"`?
As you can see some of the raw text is shows as `'` and some has `"` wrapper around it.

Comment: Python will put `"` or `'` around strings (depending on what's inside them) when it displays them to you to show you that they're strings, but the surrounding quotes aren't actually part of the string. Is this causing an actual problem with something?

Comment: If you're trying to get part between the internal quotes in the strings that have them, please show what you've tried and describe the problem you're having with it.

Comment: Please [edit] and add your input as a Python data structure and the expected output.

Comment: I havent tried anything yet. I dont know how to tell python to look for single quote. If you could tell me the diff between single and double quote, I can try something

Comment: Regarding the difference between single and double quote in Python, see [Single quote string vs double quote string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45999335/4518341)

Comment: Hey I attempted an answer, have a look

Answer (score 0):

I have something that works, improvements are welcome:

```
for rule in rules:
    print(rule)
    name = re.findall("'(.*)'", rule)
    if name:
        print(name[0])
    else:
        print(rule)
```

Output looks something like this:
(First line input, second line output.)

```
"DATA  - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA  NM Escalation'"
'DATA  NM Escalation'
"DATA  - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA  NM Escalation'"
'DATA  NM Escalation'
"DATA  - Critical/Major DATA DATA Alerts to 'DATA  NM Escalation'"
'DATA  NM Escalation'
"DATA  - Critical/Major DATA DATA Alerts to 'DATA  NM Escalation'"
'DATA  NM Escalation'
'DATA - SOM THIN Escalation'
'DATA - SOM THIN Escalation'
'DATA - SOM THIN HEARTBEAT Escalation'
'DATA - SOM THIN HEARTBEAT Escalation'
"DATA - Critical/Major DATA DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'"
'DATA NM Escalation'
"DATA - Critical/Major DATA DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'"
'DATA NM Escalation'
```

Comment: What is `rows`? a nested dict? Why not just use a list for this example?

Comment: Why are you using `re.finditer('\'', ...` instead of `re.findall("'(.*)'"...`?

Comment: rows is the output from something else, I picked out a section of the code and posted here, I can cleanup. Also, what if the diff between the 2? I used the first way I could find for returning all instances of something.

Comment: Oh actually `finditer` is fine. I meant to point out the pattern. Regex supports finding a string between two delimiters, so why not do that?

Comment: Nice idea. I could do that. I started looking for individual ' in the string. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without RegEx:

```
lst = ["DATA - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'",
       "DATA - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'",
       'DATA - SOM THIN Escalation', 
       'DATA - SOM THIN HEARTBEAT Escalation',
       "DATA - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'",
       "DATA - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'",
       "DATA - Critical/Major DATA Alerts to 'DATA NM Escalation'"]

for element in lst:
    start_idx = element.find('\'')
    if start_idx == -1:
        start_idx = 0
    end_idx = element.find('\'', start_idx+1, len(element))
    if end_idx == -1:
        end_idx = len(element)
        print(element[start_idx:end_idx])
    else:
        print(element[start_idx+1:end_idx])
```

Output:

```
DATA NM Escalation
DATA NM Escalation
DATA - SOM THIN Escalation
DATA - SOM THIN HEARTBEAT Escalation
DATA NM Escalation
DATA NM Escalation
DATA NM Escalation
```

Comment: I had something like this, I was finding start and end, I made it a bit simpler.

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus You asked what "the best way to do this" was. There is no single best way, it depends on the scenario. If you are looking for a simpler way to do it, that is a whole other question you could ask along with your working code. Of course, it would depend on your definition of 'simple'. Simple could be defined in terms of code readability, in terms of operational complexity, or in terms of some other metric. 

If you already figured out an answer to your question, you should close the question out or mark one of the answers as correct.

Comment: Hey sounds good. When I started of, I didnt know how to approach this, so didnt post any code.