# Python code to get the content of randomly generated math calculation

Tags: python, html, findall

I have a webapp that generates random equations and I am trying to automate the process of solving them with Python:

```
Can you solve the level 1?<br/><h3><div id='calc'>0 * 8</div></h3><br/>
<form action="play.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="res" />
 <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

I wrote a script to get the equation each time it is generated :

```
number =  re.findall('<div id='calc'> (.*)</div></h3><br/>', content)[0]
```

but for some reason it keeps throwing errors

```
    number =  re.findall('<div id='calc'> (.*)</div></h3><br/>', content)[0]
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone came cross this before ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999335/single-quoted-string-vs-double-quoted-string

Comment: Well, `'<div id='` is a string, `'> (.*)</div></h3><br/>'` is another string. `calc` is invalid syntax for the same reason `"hello"what"world"` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number =  re.findall(r"<div id='calc'> (.*)</div></h3><br/>", content)[0]
```

this should work , you were using single quotes `'` to define string and were also using unescaped single quotes in the string , this was leading to string just being interpreted as `<div id=` .

In python , `r"someString"` represents raw string , it is more preferrable to use them while using regex search . You can read more about raw strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it#:%7E:text=From%20the%20python%20documentation%20on,literal%20prefixed%20with%20%27r%27%20.&text=That%20obviously%20can%27t%20be,would%20completely%20lose%20its%20power.)